# Zend_Tool include_path problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path, zend-tool

I'm trying to install Zend Framework on my computer. I have done following:

1. I have placed Zend framework files on C drive, the path is like: 
   C:\ZendFramework\library
   C:\ZendFramework\bin (The bin folder contains the zf.bat, zf.sh and zf.php files)
2. I have included path in php.ini file:

   include_path = “.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZendFramework\library”

Now when I go to command prompt and type zf command, i get following error:

```
In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework is inside your include_path.
```

Can someone suggest me what im doing wrong and how to fix this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you split up the library and bin code? I don't think this is the problem but it's a little unusual.

Comment: @Phil It was already in same structure ie. library and bin folder inside the zend framework folder.

Comment: Yes, but you have the library on `C:` and the bin on `D:`

Comment: Sorry, i typed here by mistake, those both are on C:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the PHP binary / executable you're calling from the command line is using the same `php.ini` file as the web version.

Run

```
php -i
```

and look for the lines

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /path/to/ini/folder
Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/ini/folder/php.ini
```

You should also be able to see the configured include path

```
include_path => local/include/path => master/include/path
```

**Edit:** On Windows, you may want to run

```
php -i | more
```

There's a lot of information shown and I can't remember how many lines of scrollback the Windows terminal gives you. Most of what you're after will be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You know what is crazy about this error ? it solve after windows restarting .

What a great operating system is windows , 99 percent of its problems solved by restarting .